# Node - Express - Angular, why does not load JSs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, oauth-2.0

I succesfully builded a stack with those guys. It's a form which interact with an Oracle database.

Now I'm adding the authentication, demanding it to an OAuth2 server using the "client-oauth2" module for nodejs. This is the code in Node.js:

```
requireLogin = function (req, res, next) {
    var uri=ServAuth.code.getUri();
    res.redirect(uri);
};

app.get('/auth/callback', function (req, res) {
        ServAuth.code.getToken(req.url)
        .then(function (user) {
                console.log(user); //=> { accessToken: '...', tokenType: 'bearer', ... }
                user.request({
                    method: 'get',
                    url: 'https://aut.server.blabla.bla/api/Me'
                }).then(function (res) {
                    res.body.forEach(function (item){
                        if (item.Type=="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name") {
                                logged_user=item.Value;
                        }
                    });
                  })
                  return res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../public/form.html')); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
        });
});


app.use('/form', requireLogin);
```

If I call "myserver.bla/form", I am correctly redirected to the login page of the OAuth2 server; then I log in and grant the access.
Then the page "form.html" is loaded, but I see in the browser console the error:

Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module NSW_PCB_QC due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'NSW_PCB_QC' is not available!

Note that NSW_PCB_QC is the name of the angular application (ng-app="NSW_PCB_QC").

But if i load directly the form.html, bypassing the authentication, calling "myserver.bla/form.html", then all the angular modules are correctly loaded.

Where is the problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: can you show the content of form.html?

Comment: Hi @ruedamanuel, and thank you for looking at it. The form.html is 320 lines. Which part do you think can be helpful?

Comment: I'd like to see the paths to the js scripts you're loading because it seems like the relative paths from your html may be referencing something that doesn't exist in the /form route scenario because of a potential lack of static file location declaration (just a theory)

Comment: ok, these are the declarations:  
       <script src="js/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-file-upload.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services/services.js"></script>

Comment: Try adding a / before each path. My guess is that they're not rooted equally in both of the scenarios you describe.

Comment: You rock man, that works! I think you can write a formal answer, for the stackoverflow to be happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the relative paths in the js scripts are pointing to different locations depending on how the file is served. The fix is to root the paths from the same location by adding a `/` in front of them so a path that looked like

`<script src="js/services/services.js"></script>`

should look like

`<script src="/js/services/services.js"></script>`